Why Does Boost.Test Ignore Parameter "--list_content"?
I build my project, which includes unit tests implemented using boost test.  At the command line I do:
./my-test-suite --list_content

As I would expect, it generates a hierarchical list of all the unit tests.
On a remote server, our project gets built as part of continuous integration.  If I remote in to the server and run the same command, it ignores the flag and simply executes all the tests.  If I try to replace that flag with an invalid one e.g. --x then I get a syntax error.  So it appears to be checking that the flag is valid, but then ignoring it.
Clearly the problem is caused by some difference between my local build and the remote one, but what would cause boost test to ignore the --list_content flag?
Tried:
./my-test-suite --list_content

Expected: hierarchical list of all the unit tests
Actual result: executed unit tests
